# Read or update quickly hundred millions of relations on Solr

Tags: solr, database-performance, bigdata, database, nosql

### 1st post : SOLR

My team and I have a problem with *Solr*, we failed to find a solution, however we think a lot about it. So we decided to ask here.

**Problematic** : Read and updates relations very quickly between an *Element* with few millions (and possibly more) *Sub-element* relations.

Currently we have a structure like this :

```
ELEMENT 
{ 
    id: 1, 
    name : element1 
}, 
{ 
    id: 2, 
    name : element2 
}, 
[...]
{ 
    id: 10000, 
    name : element10000 
}

SUBELEMENT
{ 
    id: 1, 
    ids_elements : 1117|165|27|32|4577
    name : subelement1 
}, 
{ 
    id: 2, 
    ids_elements : 1117|416|278
    name : subelement2 
}, 
[...]
{ 
    id: 15000000, 
    ids_elements : 1117|2428|3457|5475|32|958
    name : subelement15000000 
}
```

(I use big ID because it corresponds to our needs)

With this method, we can easily get every *Sub-element* belonging to an *Element* (very quickly, like 10-20 milliseconds to get 100000 *Sub-element*).
But, taking the example above, removing *Element* "1117" on every *Sub-element*, the time for the update is too long (like 10 sec for 100000 updates).

I would like a structure like that :

```
ELEMENT 
{ 
    id: 1, 
    name : element1,
    ids_subelements : 1|2|3|...12458765|12458766... (few millions)
}, 
{ 
    id: 2, 
    name : element2 
    ids_subelements : 1|2|3|...12458765|12458766... (few other millions)
}, 
[...]
{ 
    id: 10000, 
    name : element10000 
    ids_subelements : 1|2|3|...12458765|12458766... (few other millions)
}
```

But we are out of the *Solr* limits.

Has someone solved this problem before ? Or has an idea to get the
right data structure for *Solr* ?

Is *Solr* the best solution for this kind of interaction ?

Thank you for your time !

### Update 1 : SQL

It's already denormalized in *Solr*. In *Sql* normalized database, we have something like this (I explain it for a better understanding of the problem):

```
ELEMENT(id_element, name)
ELEMENT_OWN_SUBELEMENT(id_element, id_subelement)
SUBELEMENT(id_subelement, name_subelement)
```

So in *Sql* we need to update data this way :

```
DELETE FROM element_own_subelement 
    WHERE id_element = :id_element 
    AND id_subelement = :id_subelement; 
-- (one row concerned);

DELETE FROM element_own_subelement 
    WHERE id_element = :id_element; 
-- (potentially there are millions data concerned)

DELETE FROM element_own_subelement 
    WHERE id_subelement = :id_subelement; 
-- potentially there are thousands data concerned)
```

And it's the same for the insert *Sql* requests. We need to insert millions data in *element_own_subelement* in less than few seconds.

We turned ourselves to *Solr* to solves reading problem. And it did it ! But we didn't solve the insert/update performance problems.

### Update 2 : concrete case

I'm trying to explain our problem with a concrete case :

SQL :

```
-- Main data
POINT_OF_INTEREST (id_poi, name, [...])

-- Datasets & filtering
DATASET(id_dataset, name, [...])
DATASET_OWN_POINT_OF_INTEREST(id_dataset, id_poi)
FILTERING(id_filtering, id_dataset)

-- Data displaying
MODULE (id_module, name, [...])
MODULE_OWN_POINT_OF_INTEREST(id_module, id_poi)
```

So :

- We group our data into datasets
- We associate datasets to a module
- A dataset can be filtered for a module
- We define displayed data of a module based on filtered datasets => It's only at this time we insert the documents in the *SOLR* core.

Example of a document from our *SOLR* core :

```
SOLR core "POINT_OF_INTEREST": 
{
    id_poi : 13,
    ids_modules : 1|5|8|7|24, /* Results of the filtering */
    name : "POI thirteen",
    ids_datasets : 25|5|7
}
```

To get data from the module "24", I have to request the "point_of_interest" core like this : `ids_modules:24`. It's really fast.

However, if I save a new filtering, I must do these actions in my *SOLR* core :

- remove the number "24" in the field "ids_modules" relating to all documents which aren't in the filtering data results
- add the number "24" in the field "ids_modules" relating to all documents which are in the filtering data results.
  This action is very slow, considering we have potentially 1 / 2 millions data to update many times a day.

I want to solve these 2 problematics:

- If I can make the complex filtering operation more quickly with SOLR than SQL
- If there is a way to make work my data system without systematically to do hundred thousands updates on the *SOLR* core

### Update 3 : example from *SOLR* database

```
{
    "votes_moins": "",
    "id_module": "957654|1445047|1485752|1445843|1854865|1491371|1445993|1478994|1965107|1755131|1725201|1785227|1564235|1585245|1545261|1255272|1542273|1585349|1545434|1585444|1115583|1225671|1585672|1588712|1545730|1775826|1596666|1555988|1675344|1256417|16456683|1856983|1757004|12571566|1715593|1457200|1757218|1777428|172455|1845053|1058425|108594|1885677|1748751|14874647|184817|1955120|1569536|1945635|1259825|2120353|2075726|2850779|2221051|2121129|2421264|2331600|28561607|27771611|2562107|2782553|2225916|2663224|2653225|2235717|2442252|249491|2251440|265069|2365104|2687789|275048|4270620|275092|270278|65273947|257425|274451|7275509|2275811|272605|4527690|279721|2277630|2754808|278038|5280652|2080935|280599|2481710|8281161|328211145|2815958|285219|22823435|2686666|2885978|289807|294024|729044|2292156|2892216|2902128|1029256|2932089|2954401|290488|289934|306105|304509|307616|380725|3907598|3208855|3059794|3310714|311079|3151060|315536|351598",
    "adresse.altitude": 0,
    "id_objet": "1886416_0",
    "id_flux": "101|11158|32548|10365460|104686456|1024537|1024568|1054686|1844859|1986559",
    "adresse.ville": "Varangéville",
    "id_categories": "",
    "type": 5,
    "difficulte": "16|17",
    "id_circuit": "124785_0",
    "utilisateur": "u47852;PPDA Tourisme",
    "id_sous_categories": "",
    "publication_cirkwi": 1,
    "description_fr_FR": "Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour réaliser un livre spécimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siècles, mais s'est aussi adapté à la bureautique informatique, sans que son contenu n'en soit modifié. Il a été popularisé dans les années 1960 grâce à la vente de feuilles Letraset contenant des passages du Lorem Ipsum, et, plus récemment, par son inclusion dans des applications de mise en page de texte, comme Aldus PageMaker.",
    "date_creation": 1478509817,
    "date_modification": 1473033625,
    "adresse.cp": "87456",
    "adresse.rue": "",
    "langue": "fr_FR",
    "id_locomotions": "13|48|74|18",
    "adresse.numero_rue": "",
    "votes_plus": "7852",
    "distance": 189654,
    "publication_reseau": 1,
    "pseudo_utilisateur": "PPDA1",
    "id_utilisateur_auteur": "u47852",
    "publication_prive": 0,
    "latlng": "49.1234,7.1234",
    "geo": [
      "49.1234,7.1234"
    ],
    "url_image": "[...]/mypicture.jpg",
    "stats_consultation": 20568,
    "titre_fr_FR": "Example",
    "titre_fr_FR_tri": "Example",
    "_version_": "155642045896312192"
  }
```

*(values are fakes)*

The worst keys for performance are "id_module" and "id_flux".
Fields declaration in *data-config.xml*

```
<field column="id_module" name="id_module" />
<field column="id_flux" name="id_flux" />
```

Fields declaration in *myschema.xml*

```
<field name="id_module" type="splitPipeTexte" indexed="true" />
<field name="id_flux" type="splitPipeTexte" indexed="true" />
```

Where "splitPipeTexte" is declared like this :

```
<fieldType name="splitPipeTexte" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\|"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I'm aware of that's a complex problem. With my post I search some reflections about this data system, or reacts about an error of conception. Not necessarily a complete solution.

Thanks !

Comment: You can do some mapping, see: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler However, I am not sure that is what you are after. Could you clarify if it is the underlying index structure, the actual data structure to be indexed or the view of the data you are indexing that you want to rejig. Thanks

Comment: This look a lot more like a classic database job than a Solr job. You don't seem to have any text search capabilities, so what do you hope to accomplish by using Solr?

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh : The main problem is the time to update 100000 documents in SOLR. We need an other point of view, maybe that's data structure we need to change. It's like the "one-to-few" / "one-to-many" / "one-to-squillions" explanation for Mongo [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at this problem from the wrong end of the stick. You need to organize your data in Solr for **search**, not just try to map your structure.

Most probably you will flatten (denormalize) your structures into flat records. And, if you have very complex structures, you may end up storing your original information in a separate (graph?) database and returning just IDs from Solr. The more complex original structure is, the likelier that would be the case.

Comment: I edited the initial subject to answer you.Thanks for your opinion ! It's really helpful ;)

Comment: It is still not clear what you search by. Do you actually search all those elements you keep modifying? Why do they need to be in Solr? 

Also, did you test the speed of regenerating those records from scratch instead of updating them? Because updating a record requires reconstructing it first from - relatively inefficient - stored representation. Updated document is actually a new document replacing old one

Comment: All elements need to ben in SOLR because complex search are made on them. Search that we can't do in SQL with a decent response time. I updated the initial post with a new part to complete my explanation. I'm going to test if regenerating the records from scratch is a good solution. Thanks =)

Comment: Perhaps your representation is too high a level. What about representing very specific point-presence as a document and just duplicate the record. Or have one of the axis (less frequently one) as a hierarchical parent-child representation and then the other axis as separate document occurrences. Not sub-sub child though as the whole record tree has to be regenerated together. Then you can use join queries. As it is, you seem to be duplicating posting lists of Lucene itself, but manually.

Comment: Actually when we used join queries, a join on 1 document takes 50ms, a join on 10 documents takes 500ms... So it's unusable. Maybe we miss something to optimize the join utilisation (read one row in SOLR takes normally 1 to 5 ms only). I added a real case from our database in the part "Update 3"

Comment: But does that structure solve your reindexing speed problem? Because that's what this question was about. If yes, then you can further iterate on the search, such as trying numeric data types instead of strings, possibly combined with docValues.

Comment: I gonna submit these remarks to my coworkers. Thanks a lot !